# Is there a set which is reflexive, not symmetrical, not antisymmetrical and transitive?

Tags: relations, order-theory

On the topic relations,
is there any set in a relation R on 
   $$ A = \{0,1,2,\{3\},4\} $$
which is reflexive, not symmetrical, not antisymmetrical and transitive?
If a relation is transitive, shouldn't it also be at least antisymmetrical?
For instance if the set is 
   $$R = \{(0,1),(1,2),(0,2)\}$$
R should be transitive because
 $$(0,1) \land(1,2) \implies (0,2)$$
If R is transitive it should also be at least antisymmetrical, because
$$(0,1)\land(1,0)\implies 1=0$$
The implication should be true because $$(1,0)\not\in R$$
$$ 1 \land0\implies0$$
$$ (0\implies 0) \Longleftrightarrow 1$$
is a true implication.

Is something wrong in my logical understanding on this topic? Am I missing something, I am not quite sure, if I really understood it correctly.

Comment: Are you sure about your set $A$?  A set with elements $1, 2, 4 \in \mathbb N$, and the element, a set, $\{3\}$?

Comment: To be reflexive, you'd need $R$ to include $(1, 1), (2, 2), (\{3\}, \{3\}),$ and $(4, 4)$.

Comment: The four properties are independent of each other. *Antisymmetrical* allows only one-way paths between ANY different nodes. *Symmetrical* insists on "no path between a,b or two-way path". Again, this holds for ANY a,b. Mohammad has given the smallest convenient relation (unless you want to have $\{3\}$ and not $3$ :)

Comment: yes, I am 100% sure. It is part of a set of exercises on the topic

Comment: Great. Just wanted to confirm, because the given answer is then incorrect.

Comment: if you'd change the $3$ for $\{3\}$ would it be correct then? Why would it be correct? I'd really like to understand it, rather than just having the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  $$R = \{(0,0),(1,1),(2,2), (\{3\},\{3\}), (4,4),(1,2),(1,\{3\}),(\{3\},1)\}$$

Comment: The set is not on which $R$ is a relation appears not to be $\{1, 2, 3, 4, \}$, which is the set on which your relation is built.  The asker's set is $\{1, 2, \{3\}, 4\}$, unless the asker made a mistake in giving the set, which may be the case, $3 \notin A$.

Comment: The set is as given with the $$\{3\}\in A$$

Comment: can you give a little more detail on your answer?

Comment: @amWhy but it doesn't matter. Any set with 4 elements will do.

Comment: It matters as long as $3 \neq \{3\}$, Jakobian.  All this user has had to do for nearly the past 15 minutes is adapt his notation to fit the question.  But $3 \notin A$, whereas $\{3\} \in A$.

Comment: It doesn't matter as in, our relation exists on $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ iff it exists on $\{1, 2, \{3\}, 4\}$

Comment: I suggested an edit on the answer.
It really does matter.

Comment: @ThomasChristopherDavies  Thanks for the edit.